# Ruby equivalent to JavaScript operator `||`

Tags: ruby, date

How can this be achieved in Ruby? Can it be done without repeating the variable?
Javascript:

```
b = a || 7
```

This assigns `a` if `a` is not `0` and `7` otherwise

One specific case is converting date.wday to 7 if it returns 0 (Sunday).

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe `[date.wday, 7].detect { i != 0 }`

Comment: Given that [0 is not falsey in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387515/why-treat-0-as-true-in-ruby) it's logically impossible to get what you want. You would have to perform at least one comparison before using the value.

Comment: Regarding your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37973701/1): just use `cwday` (instead of `wday`) – it returns `7` (instead of `0`) if the date is a Sunday ;-)

Comment: wait... Must you use a Date method like `wday` or not?

Comment: I had to convert to datetime first, but `cwday` solved my case.

Comment: come on @Aurimas isn't there any chance to choose my answer? :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just out of curiosity:

```
class Object
  def javascript_or?(other)
    (is_a?(FalseClass) || nil? || '' == self || 0 == self) ? nil : self
  end
end
```

and:

```
a = b.javascript_or?(7)
```

Comment: Readers: mudsie has gone off his medication.

Comment: Aye. It’s time to get my pills, thanks @CarySwoveland for the reminder! See ya all tomorrow.

Comment: Rubyist will to power

Comment: Could also `case self` which might be faster than this chain of `||` operators.

Comment: @tadman Yeah, I thought about it (though I doubt it could be any faster,) but I on purpose made this answer as cryptic as possible.

Answer (score 6):

There are only two falsy values in Ruby: `nil` and `false`. So, if you really want this approach

```
a = b == 0 ? 7 : b
```

is a plausible solution, because `0` can't be evaluated as `false`.

However, a better option for your need is [`cwday`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-cwday), and not [`wday`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-wday). Then you don't need to make this comparison anymore, because it returns `1` for Monday, `2` for Tuesday, and finally `7` for Sunday, as you need.

```
date = Date.new(2016,19,6) # => Jun 19 2016, Sunday
date.cwday # => 7
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland it's because you already have a 5-digit reputation here, Cary (; I'm just hi-lighting the most important part.

Comment: Frankly, I have a 3 digits (and one decimal point, though,) but I don’t need the bold face either.

Comment: For the sake of entropy constancy I upvoted it to give 10 rep more :)

Answer (score 3):

For the particular case of `0` and `7`:

```
a = (b + 6) % 7 + 1
```

:)

Comment: :) Nice! Readable as hell!

Answer (score 2):

You can use ternary operator:

```
 date.wday == 0 ? 7 : date.wday
```

Comment: That I could figure out by myself, any better versions? I edited the question to be just Ruby, not Rails

Comment: Ruby does not treat 0 as nil/false. It is one of the things you have to get used to. A better way would be to add your custom method to the Date class. You can find an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343555/ruby-extend-date-class-to-add-new-method

Comment: 0 evaluating to true is just part of the language.  It's intentional.  See, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10387572/6441528 .  If you want an exception, you should do something like build a utility class that provides one.  I personally wouldn't override Date, at least not if you're working collaboratively.  It'll just confuse anyone who shares your code.

Comment: @hightempo: Who said something about overriding? I said, "create your custom method".

Comment: @Aurimas: I don't know if you could figure out about ternary operator by yourself, considering that you could not figure out that 0 in Ruby is not nil/false, which should be the case for operator-|| usage.

Comment: While I would use `cwday`, I think this is a close second. I have no idea why it was downvoted, unless it was by the OP, who found it insulting.

Comment: @gen, I knew 0 is not false in Ruby before I asked, I actually had used your answer before asking the question. The problem is when the variable in question has very long name. In my case the rest of the line was already complicated enough so I couldn't make it even less readable.

Comment: @Aurimas: A long name should not be an issue. If you have a long name, create an alias with a short name and be done with it. Or create a custom method that does what you want (or use another API method, such as cwday). There is no need to expect a functionality from another language to be in a new language. Beside, I think even the creator of JS has said that decision of making 0 to be false was a bad idea. The semantics of || is "false/nill or else", and 0 is neither.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing here is less of a logical problem and more of a mapping one:

```
WEEKDAY_MAP = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = k < 7 ? k : nil }.merge(0 => 7)
```

This one re-writes 1..6 to be the same, but 0 becomes 7. All other values are `nil`.

Then you can use this to re-write your day indicies:

```
b = WEEKDAY_MAP[a]
```

If at some point you want to tinker with the logic some more, that's also possible.

Comment: Nice, but doesn't it look a bit more complicated than `day || 7` ? :D

Comment: @Aurimas; That is actually pretty good solution because after initialization (just once), you will not need to use any logical operations to determine your value.

Comment: @Aurimas Since Ruby is extremely strict about what's *false* in a logical sense, `|| 7` is never going to happen so you may as well abandon that idea: The *When in Rome* principle applies here. If you're doing a mapping operation, express it as such. In other languages you can take advantage of zero being a *false* value so the simplest expression of your desire does vary considerably depending on constraints.

Comment: In fact, this is the best answer here, hence it narrows down the fact this is a mapping issue.